# Error PHP Uncaught Error: Failed opening required

Tags: php, index

Hola buenas tengo un error en PHP y no tengo idea de qué es lo que esta fallando:

```
Warning: require_once(Views/home/home.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\tienda_robinson\Libraries\Core\Views.php on line 10

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Failed opening required 'Views/home/home.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\tienda_robinson\Libraries\Core\Views.php:10 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\tienda_robinson\Controllers\Home.php(9): Views->getView('home', 'Views/home/home...') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\tienda_robinson\index.php(37): home->home('') #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\tienda_robinson\Libraries\Core\Views.php on line 10
```

Comment: Es importante que entiendas los mensajes de error **siempre**, aunque esten en inglés.  ¿Si copias ese texto y lo pegas en el google translate sigues sin entender el error?  ¿ni mínimamente?

Comment: Lectura sugerida: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Saludos.